# Inno Setup compiles differently on different machines

Tags: inno-setup

My colleague and I both use *Inno Setup 5.5.9 (a)* for packaging.  We have same spec computers and are compiling from the same source code.

When I compile the project, the resulting **setup.exe** is 98Mb.
When my colleague compiles the same project, it is 47Mb.

Both installers behave correctly in the same way.

What could be causing my output to be twice the size of his?

Comment: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection Review the Files section. Very likely your machine gives the installer more files if wildcard is used.

Comment: Show us compiler output log from both machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for pointing me to the log file.  They were the same between the two machines, but one file stood out: the .Net Framework bootstrap installer.

While we both drew from the same source control, his computer was not configured for [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) and only had reference stubs for the bootstrap installers.  Inno Setup wasn't failing or showing errors because files with those names technically existed.  None of our test machines or existing clients activate the bootstrap installers any more so it never caused an error during install either.

Our machines now produce the same output.